# Epsilon-greedy algorithm

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I understand epsilon-greedy algorithm, but there is one point of confusion.

1. Is it average **reward or value** that it keeps track of? Most of the time, it is explained in the context of multi-armed bandit. However, there is no distinction of reward / value in the problem of multi-armed bandit.
2. is epsilon-greedy algorithm a subset of Q-learning? The vague definition of Q-learning seems to be: approximating the optimal Q-function by utilizing past experiences.

Answer (score 3):

Epsilon-greedy is a policy, not an algorithm. It is exclusive of discrete action problems: you select the action according to

```
argmax Q(s,a) with probability 1-epsilon
random otherwise
```

You can use with Q-learning, SARSA, DDPG, policy gradient, ...